# cyclic text in latex with arrows and number on them

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles

how can i write my cyclic text like this:[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: i couldnt find anything close:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with Tikz. If you want to learn Tikz, I suggest you read the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). It contains a lot of good examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->]
        \node (a) at (90:2cm)  {Democrat};
        \node (b) at (-30:2cm) {Republician};
        \node (c) at (210:2cm) {Third};
        
        \draw (-20:2cm) arc (-20:60:2cm) node[midway, right] {{\footnotesize 5 voters}};
        \draw (120:2cm) arc (120:200:2cm) node[midway, left] {{\footnotesize 7 voters}};
        \draw (220:2cm) arc (220:320:2cm) node[midway, below] {{\footnotesize 1 voter}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: circle diagramm]

If you want to use this inside your document, make sure to add `\usepackage{tikz}` to your preamble.